# How to Delete a row from more than one table with one sql query where email id is same

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, join, sql-delete

```
Table1

 - name
 - phone
 - age
 - email

Table2

 - name
 - phone 
 - age
 - email
```

I want to delete those data which has the same email in both tables.

Comment: USe 2 `DELETE` statements. DML statements can only effect 1 table at a time. If `table2` the had the Primary Key of `Table1` in it, you can implement cascading though.

Comment: If you don't know how to use `DELETE` then I suggest you start learning how to use your preferred Search Engine and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support multi-table deletes, so you need two `delete` statements (as commented by Larnu).

But it is still a bit tricky since you need to keep track of the emails that were deleted by the first statement so you can use them in the second one. I would recommend a table variable, that you can feed with a `output` clause:

```
begin transaction;

declare @deleted_emails table (email nvarchar(100)); 
-- or whatever datatype/length you use

delete from table1
output deleted.email into @deleted_emails
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.email = table1.email)

delete from table2
where exists (select 1 from @deleted_emails d where d.email = table2.email);

commit transaction;
```

Wrapping the code in a `transaction` makes it atomic (that is, the changes done by both statements are commited or rolled back together).